# Retrieving Email from Google Plus account on Android app

Tags: java, android, email, google-plus

So, I am letting a user sign into their Google+ account on my app. Right now I am able to get their profile URL and display name. What I want to do now is get their email. I'm not sure about how to get this information. I haven added the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read` and it successfully asks for my permission to access my email when I sign in. I'm just unsure of how to retrieve the user email, now.

For username, I do this:

`String currentPersonName = mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson().getDisplayName();`

So basically what I want to do is something like this:

`String currentPersonEmail = mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson().getEmail();`

but obviously this isn't the correct way. Does anyone know how to get the email? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the user's email address:

```
 private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, null)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();

 emailAddr = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
```

An alternative way would be to query Google+'s plus.profile.emails.read scope (as you have done) but instead of displayName, look for "emails" type jsons, see [code example here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people).

Comment: thanks for the post. How do I get mGoogleApiClient from a user?

Comment: I'm getting The method addConnectionCallbacks(GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) in the type GoogleApiClient.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity)

Comment: Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient); needs extra permission in marshamallow. is there any other way to get the email?